# CURL HTTP CODE 403

Tags: php, curl

I am getting curl http code as 403:

> The user myuser was denied access to perform the operation on the object defect due to the following reasons: The permission setting for operation Create doesn't allow user to perform the required operation on the secured object.

Same code was working fine with 'HTTP', now it is 'HTTPS', so I updated code like added `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);` these lines and it is giving 403 as HTTP CODE. Can someone help me where I am wrong.

```
$ch = curl_init(MY_BASE_URL);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, MY_COOKIES);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, MY_COOKIES);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8","Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($myfields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response=curl_exec($ch);
$code=curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($code!=201)
{throw new Exception("Error creating defect: ".$response);}
else{echo 'Success';}
```

Comment: It is giving 403, I need 200

Comment: The problem may be related to the code, but `MY_BASE_URL` is the thing emitting the response not curl - I doubt anyone reading this question can answer it as with the info provided it's not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

try this user agent(if not works then try with random user agents)

```
$useragent= "curl/7.39.0";
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
```